# Other way for getActivity() use in service Android java

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, background-service

In my `PollFragment.java` that able to call `new PollTask((MainActivity)getActivity()).execute((Void)null);`

And in my `PollTask.java`

```
public PollTask(MainActivity activity){
        super(activity);
        TerminalCfg terminalCfg = Global.getTerminalCfg();
        terminalId = terminalCfg.getTerminalId();
        retailerAcc = terminalCfg.getRetailerAcc();
        internalId = APIUtil.getInternalId(activity);
        username = APIUtil.getUsername(activity);
    }
```

And now I want to call the  `new PollTask((MainActivity)getActivity()).execute((Void)null);`
in `MyBackgroundService` with extends `Service` like below :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new PollTask((MainActivity)getActivity()).execute((Void)null);
        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Is there any other way to replace the `getActivity()` to call the method?

Answer (score 2):

A `Service` is a separate component from an `Activity` and thus you cannot get a reference to it using `getActivity()`.  Services are designed for doing work not visible to the user, including (but not limited to) background work on a separate thread from the UI thread. Services are more robust and offer more control over what work is being performed that is not visible to the user.  They do not require an `Activity` to run.

An `AsyncTask` is a simple way of doing work from **inside** an `Activity` on a separate `Thread` from the UI thread.

Basically, you dont want or need an `AsyncTask` in a `Service`.

Instead, in your `Service` you should either spawn a `Thread`, or use `IntentService` which will handle creating a worker `Thread` for you.  Then when you are finished, send an intent back to the `Activity` either by starting it or using a `LocalBroadcast`

Alternatively, you can tie a `Service` to an `Activity` and provide methods that the `Service` and `Activity` can call directly on each other through an `IBinder` interface.  These are called bound services and will only be alive as long as the `Activity` is alive.

### Try an IntentService

I think your best bet is to try learning how to use an `IntentService`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Do you mind to have source code for me to more understand of it.